# Strange artefacts appear on CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, artifacts, texturepacker

I have a CCLayer class imported onto a game layer
strangely all the the sprites have "artefacts" that seem to appear from nowhere since I have checked and re-exported all of the files

Is some setting or something else that could cause this to happen?

I'm new at this
but I have checked so far:
set to PixelFormat_RGBA8888
PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES
png's are clear from artefact (28bit with transparency)
Textures are made with texture packer with "pre-multiplied"

The Background is a CCLayer
The Mine is a CCLayer 
both are added to the game layer (cclayer also) as "addChild"

```
     backgroundManager = [[BackGround alloc] init];
    [self addChild:backgroundManager z:0];

    myShip = [[Ship alloc]init];
    [self addChild:myShip z:5];
```

[image]

Comment: hmmm interestingly I have found that the problem may be with the export settings in texture packer

since if I just import a single sprite png the transparency works,
My texture packer is 3yrs old - so maybe there has been some change in the settings... Im going to experiment and see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it was the settings in texture packer
after a few changes in the settings they now seem to load fine.
with no artifacts

use pre multiple
trim not crop
and give a little more inner padding

hope it helps someone else (since it was driving me a little crazy)